# kableExtra: Hyperlink in footnote of a table

Tags: r, knitr, kableextra, kable

I looked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45397545/707145) but the given method does not seem work with footnotes (See MWE). I wonder how to add hyperlink in table footnotes using `kableExtra` package.

```
knitr::kable(
              x       = mtcars[1:4, 1:5]
            , format  = "latex"
            , caption = "Table Caption with hyperlink[note]"
            , escape  = FALSE
            ) %>%
  kableExtra::add_footnote("\\href{https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra}{kableExtra}")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With kableExtra > 0.5.0, you can use `escape` in footnote.

```
library(kableExtra)
knitr::kable(mtcars[1:4, 1:5], 
         format  = "latex", 
         caption = "Table Caption with hyperlink[note]", 
         escape  = FALSE
        ) %>%
  add_footnote("\\href{https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra}{kableExtra}",
                       escape = F)
```

Comment: Thanks @Hao for wonderful package and nice solution. I do have [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46156841/707145) on `kableExtra`. Would appreciate if you have a look and help me on that too. Thanks