# kableExtra: Put a few rows of a table into many categories programmatically

Tags: r, knitr, kableextra, kable

Currently `kableExtra 0.5.1` only supports *Put a few rows of a table into one category*. I wonder if there is any tweak to Put a few rows of a table into many categories programmatically like `group_rows(kable_input = x, group_label = c("Group 1", "Group 2"), start_row = c(1, 5), end_row = c(2, 6))`. Thanks

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

x <- knitr::kable(head(mtcars, 10), "latex")
kableExtra::group_rows(kable_input = x, group_label = c("Group 1", "Group 2"), start_row = c(1, 5), end_row = c(2, 6))
```

Comment: Just do a loop, like your other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With dev version of `kableExtra`, you can use the `index` option to group rows in a similar way with `add_header_above()`.

```
kable(mtcars[1:10, 1:5], "latex", booktabs = T) %>%
  group_rows(index = c(" " = 3, "Group 1" = 3, "Group 2" = 4))
```

Comment: This is cool. However, I would prefer to have a function with capabilities  like `Labs  <- c("Group 1", "Group 2") Start <- c(1, 5) End   <- c(2, 6) knitr::kable(mtcars[1:10, 1:5], "latex", booktabs = T) %>%
kableExtra::group_rows(group_label = Labs, start_row = Start, end_row = End)` so `Labs` and can be given outside the main function. Any thoughts, please.

Comment: @MYaseen208 You can always build index outside of the function as well.